# Ошибка при установке SQL Server 2016 Express

Tags: sql-server

```
Exit code (Decimal)
-2068052081
Error description
Во время установки сборки "Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.1833",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"" произошла ошибка. 
Дополнительные сведения см. в центре справки и поддержки. HRESULT: 0x80070422.
```

Windows 10, x64!!! Пробовал SQL Server 2012 перед єтим поставить тоже была подобная ошибка. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: у тебя отключены обновления windows?

Comment: А ты случайно не 32 разрядный сервер ставишь?

Comment: падает сразу же, на первом же компоненте. служба Windows Modules Installer запущена? не выставлена в disabled?

Comment: @PashaPash Да. Включил. Все установилось. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

падает сразу же, на первом же компоненте. служба Windows Modules Installer запущена? не выставлена в disabled? – PashaPash

Answer (score 1):

1. Зайдите в «Выполнить» (Win+R) и пропишите команду `services.msc`
2. В открывшемся окне «Службы» найдите «Центр обновления Windows», войдите в «Свойства».
3. На вкладке «Общее» в строке «Тип запуска» выберите «Автоматически», нажмите «Применить».
4. Перезагрузка

Еще следует проверить, хватает ли пользователю прав

Comment: Эта служба выполняется. Значит не в этом проблема.

Comment: @PeterKiuppier проверь есть ли у пользователя права администратора